# Randomly Add a Class in For Loop

Tags: jquery

On document ready, I am populating variables and using them to run a for-loop that creates a number of divs with a class of `box`. I would like to add a class of `possible` to those `box`
divs at random so that they are evenly distributed. For example, say there ends up being 100 divs with class `box`, I'd like a random number of those divs to also have a class of `possible`.

Any ideas as to how I can do this? I have included my current code below.

Thanks

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
    var wrapperWidth = wrapper.width();
    var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();
    var wrapperArea = wrapperWidth * wrapperHeight;
    var boxWidthHeight = 30;
    var boxArea = boxWidthHeight * boxWidthHeight;
    var boxCount = wrapperArea / boxArea;
    alert(boxCount);
    for(var i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box"></div>');
    }
});
```

Comment: why dont you generate random numbers store it in a `array` and whatever the values in array if matches with value `i` in `for loop` will active the div with class `box`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use Math.random().

In pseudo-code:

```
if (Math.random() < .5) //Or any other fraction
   addDivWithPossibleClass();
else
   addDivWithoutPossibleClass();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
for(var i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {
        var newClass = "box" + ((i % 2 == 0) ? " posible" : "");
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="'+newClass+'"></div>');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Im no pro but I got it by doing this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var wrapper = $('.wrapper');
var wrapperWidth = wrapper.width();
var wrapperHeight = wrapper.height();
var wrapperArea = wrapperWidth * wrapperHeight;
var boxWidthHeight = 31;
var boxArea = boxWidthHeight * boxWidthHeight;
var boxCount = 30;
//alert(boxCount);
for(var i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) { 
    $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box'+getRandom()+'">'+i+'</div>');    
}

function getRandom() {
//get a random number between 1 and 10
var randomSomething = Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1);
// if the number is over 5 return the "possible" class else dont
    if(randomSomething > 5){
        return ' possible';
        }else{return '';}
}

});
```

increase or lower the 10 to affect how many random possibles appear.

Answer (score 0):

Here this will help you a lot.

```
for(var i = 0; i < boxCount; i++) {

    // generating a random number between boxCount
    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*boxCount)

    //checking if that is odd or even, based on that giving out result
    if (randomnumber%2 == 0) {
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box"></div>');
    } else {
        $('.wrapper').append('<div class="box possible"></div>');
    }

}
```